# Asp.net core route constraints for default guid

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

Is there any way of adding a route constraint for a default GUID and if the value is a default GUID then to fail the request?

I know that you can use a regex, but what would the regex be for such a constraint ?

Also currently I'm usinga custom ValidationAttribute but the status code is not appropriate 400, I would like to move it to route level which would return a 404

Answer (score 0):

You can define a check for your guid such as.

```
[HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
public IActionResult GetById(Guid id)
{
   if (id.Equals(Guid.Empty))
   {
      return NotFound();
   }
 }
```

Another way is to create an action specifically for this guid.

```
[HttpGet("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")]
public IActionResult GetBySepcificId(Guid id)
{
    return NotFound();
}
```